# Move clustered SQL from one network to another

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005, cluster

We have a clustered SQL server (2k5 Std) that's currently being hosted on 1 of 2 subnets on the server. We'd like to retire the subnet the SQL cluster is on as we're experiencing default gateway issues with the servers being multi-homed.

My question is what is the best way to migrate the SQL cluster from one network to the other? It would reside in the same cluster, same name, just dependent on another subnet.

My instinct tells me to just reinstall sql into the cluster, specifying the other subnet on the install, then clean up the mess afterwards.

But I was wondering if maybe there was any other ways, perhaps a best practice that I'm not aware of.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this we simply configured SQL Server to accept conenctions on the new subnet, then configured it not to accept connections on the old subnet.